# What ascii value is at the beginning for a c++ string?

Tags: c++

so i know the last character in a string is the null character, what character is in the front? like what character is at `string[0-1]`? I tried to `cout` it but it just comes up blank. the reason i need to know this is for an if statement that checks if `string[0-1]` is equal to that character. The overall program is a calculator and I'm trying to handle user input errors like no spaces between operators and operands, problem is there is the minus sign `-` and the negative number sign `-` . so in my if statement I have `if(string[i] == '-' && string[i-1] != ' '){return false;}` but this returns false if the first number in the string is a negative number, hence my dilemma.

Comment: there is nothing in front of it, `string[-1]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @tkausl why did this question deserve a negative?

Comment: Reading outbound an array will cause an `Undefined behavior`. Uninitialized Memory addresses or variables contain garbage values.

Comment: so how would u guys check that there are spaces before and after the '-' sign except in the case where its a negative number? any help would be appreciated

Comment: you'll need a different strategy for handing minus or negative. one idea, while you're parsing, if the last thing you read was a number, you know that '-' means minus, but if the last thing you read was an operator, then it means negative

Comment: You might check index directly: `if(string[i] == '-' && i != 0 && string[i-1] != ' ')`

Comment: @Jarod42 ty this is what i needed.

Comment: The responsibility of the programmer is whether to append a null character to the end of string or get a garbage output at the end. Also the string is a set of 1 or 2 bytes characters consecutive in memory so if some variable is allocated right before then reading `index_0 - 1` will fall in that variable value which is considered an UB.

Comment: @Raindrop7: It's not the responsibility of the programmer, it is guaranteed to be done for you by the `std::string` implementation.

Comment: @Raindrop7: Reading `index_0 - 1` could fall in another variable's value, or it could fall in the code segment, or it could fall into Mars orbit. That's why it's UB.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I don't think anything about this question is about character sets?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes. Thank you. But I didn't mean `std::string` I just meant an array of characters;

Comment: @Raindrop7: Ok then that's not a string ;) (I'm being a bit pedantic for the fun of it, don't worry about it)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you you are always helpful & positive.

Comment: @Raindrop7: My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

> so i know the last character in a string is the null character

No, it isn't, but both C-string and `std::string` will put a null character *immediately after the string* for various technical reasons.

There is no such thing before the string, because there is no reason to be. A program containing the expression `string[-1]` has undefined behaviour, because that is a non-existent index in the string and there is no special case to give it any meaning.

> in my if statement I have `if(string[i] == '-' && string[i-1] != ' '){return false;}`

You can try something like:

```
if (string[i] == '-' && (i > 0 && string[i-1] != ' '))
```

I can't quite work out what your desired logic is so you'll have to tweak it to do what you want.

Comment: ok thank you for clearing this up, what i was looking for is what @jarod42 said above. it is now working.

Comment: @billy Please read the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) topic.